# Removing user controls from parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I use this code to show user control on main form

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sell sell = new Sell();
        sell.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(sell);
    }
```

I want to remove this user control from main form but this code does not working

```
this.Controls.Remove(sell);
```

I tried `this.Parent.controls.Remove(sell);` but it does not work either.
Please advise something...

Comment: First though in my mind is that it might be a scoping issue. Are you attempting to remove `sell` from within the `MainForm_Load` method or from some other method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you're creating another `Sell` control and trying to remove that? If so, that won't work because that's a different object from the one you added on form load.

One way to do what you want would be to give a name to your `Sell` control and use that name to remove it later:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sell sell = new Sell();
    sell.Name = "mainSell";
    sell.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(sell);
}

// Later...
this.Controls.RemoveByKey("mainSell");
```

Answer (score 3):

You defined sell control in `MainForm_Load` [**`scope`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and want to remove it in another scope so you can't, you can define it in more general scope and then remove it:

```
Sell sell = new Sell();
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sell.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(sell);
}

// other scope
this.Controls.Remove(sell);
```

Comment: Thanks Frédéric Hamidi and Saeed